# How to use leaflet-geomanplugin with react-leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-geoman

I tried implementing a rotate functionality on my **Rectangle** elements and stumpbled across **leaflet-geoman** which works pretty well.

```
const rect = (
      <Rectangle
        key={layer.id}
        bounds={bounds}
        eventHandlers={{
          click: () => {
           handleLayerClicked(object);
          },
          'pm:rotateend'...
        }}
      >
      </Rectangle>
    );
    layersJSX.push(rect);
  });

  return layersJSX;
```

This works fine. Even passing the event handlers like **pm:update** or **pm:rotateend** works on the component.

I cant seem to figure out how to apply a rotation on the Rectangle itself in my case? When working with plain JS like:

```
const rect = L.rectangle(bounds, {
      stroke: layer.isHighlighted,
      color: getColorForSelectedLayer(layer.id ?? ''),
    }).addTo(map);
rect.pm.rotateLayerToAngle(angle);
```

it works.

Any input is highly appreciated since I would like to use the components from **react-leaflet** along with **leaflet-geoman**.